# Representing sum types in sql with Persistent, and Esqueleto joins

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, esqueleto

I have been trying to figure out a sensible way to represent Haskell sum types in a SQL backend using persistent.

My target Haskell data type is along the lines of

```
data Widget = FooWidget Int | BarWidget T.Text

data HElement = HElement 
   { name   :: T.Text
   , widget :: Widget
   }
```

I am modeling these using the following Persistent data types:

```
Element
  name    T.Text

Foo
  elementId ElementId
  size      Int

Bar
  elementId ElementId
  colour    T.Text
```

There will only ever be either a Foo or a Bar for each Element, never both.

I want to use a `Left Outer Join` to select all my elements and the corresponding Foo OR Bar. My Esqueleto expression is:

```
select $ 
from $ \(elem `LeftOuterJoin` foo `LeftOuterJoin` bar) -> do
on (just (elem ^. ElementId) ==. foo ?. FooElementId)
on (just (elem ^. ElementId) ==. bar ?. BarElementId)
return (elem, foo, bar)
```

However, when I execute the code, I get the error:

```
user error (Postgresql.withStmt': bad result status FatalError (("PGRES_FATAL_ERROR","ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
```

If I remove the second join, giving:

```
select $ 
from $ \(elem `LeftOuterJoin` foo) -> do
on (just (elem ^. ElementId) ==. foo ?. FooElementId)
return (elem, foo)
```

The code runs without error. I'm sure it's obvious but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

---

EDIT: I found what the problem was; from the docs:

> Note carefully that the order of the ON clauses is reversed! You're
>   required to write your ons in reverse order because that helps
>   composability (see the documentation of on for more details).

The following code works (the order of the `on` expressions reversed):

```
select $
from $ \(elem `LeftOuterJoin` foo `LeftOuterJoin` bar) -> do
on (just (elem ^. ElementId) ==. bar ?. BarElementId)
on (just (elem ^. ElementId) ==. foo ?. FooElementId)
return (elem,foo,bar)
```

---

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Could you please add your answer as, well, an answer below? It's easy to miss your solution if it's part of the question, as I almost did right now.

Comment: Can someone help explain why the `just` is needed? The `elem` table is certain to have it's own `id`. I hit an error when I remove the `just`. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding as an answer as suggested by Waldheinz

---

I found what the problem was; from the docs:

> Note carefully that the order of the ON clauses is reversed! You're
>   required to write your ons in reverse order because that helps
>   composability (see the documentation of on for more details).

The following code works (the order of the `on` expressions reversed):

```
select $
from $ \(elem `LeftOuterJoin` foo `LeftOuterJoin` bar) -> do
on (just (elem ^. ElementId) ==. bar ?. BarElementId)
on (just (elem ^. ElementId) ==. foo ?. FooElementId)
return (elem,foo,bar)
```

---

Regards,

Michael